# GWT JSONObject adding an additional incorrect key when converting overlay type to json string

Tags: parsing, gwt, json

I'm encountering the following problem - I have simple GWT overlay types, and I'm trying to convert one to a JSON string on the client; I'm simply doing:

```
new JSONObject(this).toString();
```

The conversion works, but it adds an additional, incorrect key to the json string, such as:

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":value2, "$H":1}
```

where "$H":1 doesn't correspond to anything in my overlay type. 
Any idea why this is?

Any help is appreciated on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is define in this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/msg/b9f7b887b6950538)

> The $H property comes from the
>   implementation of
>   JavaScriptObject#hashCode() (in
>   com.google.gwt.cire.client.impl.Impl#getHashCode(Object)).
>
> In your case, this is due to
>   AbstractEditableCell maintaining a map
>   of value keys to their "view data",
>   and your use (I guess) of the default
>   ProvidesKey implementation
>   (SimpleProvidesKey) which directly
>   returns the item.
>
> So, when rendering, the EditTextCell
>   calls getViewData, which looks up the
>   key in the map (and thus needs the
>   hashcode of the key, hence the call to
>   hashCode), and the key is your JSO
>   (hence the new $H property).
>
> I believe that giving a ProvidesKey
>   implementation (in you case, returning
>   the name property for instance) to the
>   Celltable would solve your issue.